# Angular 6 library cannot find relative path to node_modules when distribute library to other computers

Tags: angular, angular-akita

### Original TypeScript file

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { transaction, snapshotManager } from '@datorama/akita';
> import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
> import { Business, transformBusiness } from 'smb-sp-models/business';
> import { BusinessStore } from './business.store';
> import { BusinessDataService } from './business-data.service';
>
>
> @Injectable({
> providedIn: 'root'
> })
> export class BusinessService {
>
>     constructor(
>         private businessStore: BusinessStore,
>         private businessDataService: BusinessDataService
>     ) {        
>     }
>
>     setQueryString(query: string) {
>         this.businessDataService.setQueryString(query);
>     }
>
>     get() {
>         return this.businessDataService.get().pipe(tap( (data: any) => {
>             this.businessStore.set(data.data);
>         }));
>     }
>
>     getById(id: string) {
>         return this.businessDataService.getById(id).pipe(tap( (data: any) => {
>             const entity = data;
>             this.businessStore.createOrReplace(entity.businessId, entity);
>         }));
>     }
>
>     getPage(opt?) {
>         return this.businessDataService.get(opt);
>     }
>
>     @transaction()
>     add(entity: Business) {
>         this.businessStore.add(entity);
>         return this.businessDataService.add(entity);
>     }
>
>     @transaction()
>     update(entity: Business) {
>         this.businessStore.update(entity.businessId, entity);
>         return this.businessDataService.update(entity);
>     }
>
>     @transaction()
>     replace(entity: Business) {
>         this.businessStore.createOrReplace(entity.businessId, entity);
>     }
>
>     @transaction()
>     remove(entity: Business) {
>         this.businessStore.remove(entity.businessId);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

### File in dist folder after run ng build

> ```
> import { Business } from 'smb-sp-models/business';
> import { BusinessStore } from './business.store';
> import { BusinessDataService } from './business-data.service';
> export declare class BusinessService {
>     private businessStore;
>     private businessDataService;
>     constructor(businessStore: BusinessStore, businessDataService: BusinessDataService);
>     setQueryString(query: string): void;
>     get(): import("../../../../../../../../../Volumes/TINNAKORNC/wip/web/smartbiz/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>;
>     getById(id: string): import("../../../../../../../../../Volumes/TINNAKORNC/wip/web/smartbiz/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>;
>     getPage(opt?: any): import("../../../../../../../../../Volumes/TINNAKORNC/wip/web/smartbiz/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<import("../../../../../../../../../Volumes/TINNAKORNC/wip/web/smartbiz/node_modules/@datorama/akita/src/plugins/paginator/paginator-plugin").PaginationResponse<Business>>;
>     add(entity: Business): import("../../../../../../../../../Volumes/TINNAKORNC/wip/web/smartbiz/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>;
>     update(entity: Business): import("../../../../../../../../../Volumes/TINNAKORNC/wip/web/smartbiz/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>;
>     replace(entity: Business): void;
>     remove(entity: Business): void;
> }
> ```

**Questions**
Please help me, What is the cause of this problem?  I create the library on Mac and want to distribute library to any Windows or other computers and they cannot see the path like above code (that embedded the path of Mac). Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [`ng-packagr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr)? You have to properly package your library so that it is distinguishable by `angular`. It is not just simple build javascript. Packaging shall take care of dependencies you have in your project, properly describe your exports so that importing application can use your library.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and finally I found the cause of problem. Angular try to resolve the return type that I did not declare for each method. After declared the problem gone. like this

Comment: Btw, why are you using @transaction()? Check again the docs for when to use it, in most of your code you don't need it.